# Замена текста в шаблоне Word из ячеек в Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Есть шаблон Word, в котором определенные места, текст в которых нужно заменить размечены тэгами `{ }`. Есть так же форма в Экселе в столбец `G` которой пользователь вводит данные для последующей замены в шаблон Word.

[image: screenshot]

Проблема в том что сами данные не будут статичны т.е. может понадобится другое количество строк в некоторых пунктах (например в пункте `Задачи дисциплины` их может быть как 4, так и больше либо меньше. Остальные строки при этом тоже будут менять свое положение в документе).

Не знаю даже как это реализовать в виде макроса. (Может быть вообще стоит переделать форму в экселе так, чтобы поля ввода распологались не вертикально друг под другом, а горизонтально друг за другом? Тогда у каждого поля ввода будет свой собственный столбец)

Comment: Почитайте встроенную справку MS Word по термину "Слияние". По нажатию кнопки на новом листе с предопределённым названием создаёте исходные данные в нужном для слияния формате, а потом открываете основной документ, у которого источник данных - свежесозданный лист.

Answer (score 0):

В *VBA* вставку данных из *Excel* в *Word* можно осуществить с помощью закладок (*bookmarks*).

Открыть документ *Word*, выделить место вставки данных (можно только установить курсор, вставляемый в закладку текст займет нужную длину строки). *Вставка-Закладка*, вписать имя закладки, *Добавить*. Файл можно сохранить как шаблон (*.dot, .dotx*). Документ готов к приему данных.

На листе книги *Excel* оформить диапазон данных, предназначенных для вставки в *Word*. Для удобства в соседний столбец можно вставить текст (не обязательно):  описание, наименование, в какую закладку вставляются данные и т.п.

В редакторе *VBA* в общем модуле проекта разместить код:

```
Option Explicit
Dim mDOK As Object

' функция записи текста в закладки
Function UpdateBookmarks(ByVal NameOfBookmark As String, ByVal ContentOfBookmark As String)
Dim oRng As Object
Dim oBm As Object
    Set oBm = mDOK.Bookmarks ' в переменную закладки документа
    Set oRng = oBm(NameOfBookmark).Range ' в переменную имена закладок документа
    oRng.Text = ContentOfBookmark ' содержание закладок
    oBm.Add NameOfBookmark, oRng
End Function

' заполнение закладок
Sub open_doc()
Dim oWordApl As Object
Dim sPath As String
Dim sNameDoc As String
    sNameDoc = "Проба пера" ' имя документа
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sNameDoc & ".dot" ' путь к документу имя.dot
    Set oWordApl = CreateObject("word.application") ' объект - программа Word
    Set mDOK = oWordApl.Documents.Open(sPath) ' открываем документ
    oWordApl.Visible = True ' показываем Word

    ' записываем в закладки текст из ячеек листа Excel
    With Worksheets("Источник")
        UpdateBookmarks "название_дисциплины", .Range("G2").Value
        UpdateBookmarks "код_дисциплины", .Range("G3").Value
        UpdateBookmarks "направление", .Range("G4").Value
        UpdateBookmarks "профиль подготовки", .Range("G5").Value
        ' .......................
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Отладчик ругается на данную строку `Set oRng = oBm(NameOfBookmark).Range` с ошибкой `Запрашиваемый номер семейства не существует`. И еще вопрос: вот вы в своем коде указали, что данные из Excel для замены берутся из определнных ячеек. А что если мне нужно будет добавить новую строку и данные "съедут"? Можно ли сделать так, чтоб макрос не зависел от конкретных ячеек, а был какой-то динамический диапазон или что-то подобное

Comment: Посмотрите имя закладки, которое передается при ошибке. Возможно, такой закладки нет в документе Word. Должно быть полное соответствие символов. О диапазоне: можно сделать динамическим. При этом нужен критерий (отметка, флаг), по которому можно определить начало и длину диапазона.  Если закладок много, диапазон можно загрузить в массив и работать без обращения к листу.

Comment: Можно использовать именованные диапазоны для получения информации с листа